# Global onException to handle multiple RouteBuilder classes

Tags: scala, spring-mvc, apache-camel

I need to make onException, to be global over the whole route builders I have in order not to rewrite the same line for every route builder I create .
The current scope for my exception handler is a camel context for specific route builder . I need to make route builder classes ,r1 and r2, to use the same onException().process.

The current working onException I use :

```
def configure {

     onException(classOf[CustomException]).process(exceptionProcessor).
       process(doExtraProcess)


    from(address).
            process(doSmth).
            process(doSmthElse)
  }
```

When I have moved the onException() line from configre method to be on the class level like the following :

```
  onException(classOf[CustomException]).process(exceptionProcessor).
           process(doExtraProcess)

    def configure {

        from(address).
                process(doSmth).
                process(doSmthElse)
      }
```

I got this error :

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to
>   create route route52 at: >>> OnException[[class CustomException] ->
>   [process[null], process[null]]] <<< in route:
>   Route[[From[direct:locus]] -> [OnException[[... because of ref must be
>   specified on: process[null]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ref must be specified
>   on: process[null]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, onException() needs to called by the configure() method.  Next, you can just use inheritance to reuse exception handling.  Just create a parent RouteBuilder class and put common exception handling in a method.  Then have each subclass call that common method in their configure() method...

Comment: This is exactly how we share common functionality and works pretty well so far.