# Shared Camel exception stategies

Tags: java, error-handling, exception, apache-camel

I am working on a Camel project where we are consuming multiple external partners / services. And I am struggling with error and exception management.

Currently I have a working version, but I'm really not happy with it... loads of duplicated code just for error handling. Routes look like this:

```
        from("direct:myEntryPoint")
            .errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler())

            .onException(IOException.class)
            .asyncDelayedRedelivery()
            .useOriginalMessage()
            .delayPattern("0:100;5:500;10:2000;20:60000")
            .maximumRedeliveries(-1)
            .end()

            .onException(Throwable.class)
            .handled(true)
            .to("mock:logAndStoreFailedMessage")
            .end()

            .to("mock:businessLogic");
```

Here, the behavior is simple: if there is an IOException, we consider we didn't reach the partner and will retry again later. Other exceptions are handled like critical error and we will just log that the message failed.

Some other partners are considered more critical, we don't want to retry even for IOException:

```
        from("direct:myEntryPoint")
            .errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler())

            .onException(Throwable.class)
            .handled(true)
            .to("mock:logAndStoreFailedMessage")
            .end()

            .to("mock:businessLogic");
```

And we have other behaviors too, but I don't want to spoil the post and list them all...

**My question is:**
How can we share onException logic across multiple routes?

My thoughts about this:

- I would have been more than happy with a RouteDefinition#onException(OnExceptionDefinition) method, I guess, but it does not exist... (or even a RouteDefinition#onException(Class... throwables, OnExceptionDefinition) to specify the classes)
- I tried working with ExceptionPolicyStrategy on the errorHandler, but apparently it's not build for this purpose (and didn't find a hint of this even in "Camel In Action")
- I tried building a RouteBuilder extension (like suggested in [Global onException to handle multiple RouteBuilder classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719748/global-onexception-to-handle-multiple-routebuilder-classes)), but I don't have just one onException behavior to implement but I would like to be able to choose or even build a new one and I feel it's gonna be ugly to allow that. (Edit: see below, Edit 1 & 2)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

---

**Edit 1:**

I tried a bit more subclassing RouteBuilder and arrive to something I could live with, but I'm quite confident there are some better ways out there! Here is a sample of code for the subclass:

```
public abstract class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    protected ErrorHandlerBuilder firstErrorHandler() {
        final DefaultErrorHandlerBuilder errorHandlerBuilder = super.defaultErrorHandler();

        onException(IOException.class)
                .asyncDelayedRedelivery()
                .useOriginalMessage()
                .delayPattern("0:100;5:500;10:2000;20:60000")
                .maximumRedeliveries(-1);

        onException(Throwable.class)
                .handled(true)
                .to("mock:logAndStoreFailedMessage")
                .end();

        return errorHandlerBuilder;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2:**

And of course, it is not working when you declare many `from` routes in the same RouteBuilder (because, you cannot write a general `onException` after declaring a route), so it's for single use purpose.

Anyhow, I don't mark the question as answered yet, waiting for comments and better / cleaner propositions.

Comment: @pratiyush-kumar-singh Don't do more than five or so of these tag edits at a time. They cause the edited questions to flood the front page of the site. Also, you should remove the [camel] tag because it's [deprecated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310814/proposed-make-camel-a-synonym-of-apache-camel),